# Angular js with node js issue with $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

My angularjs $http.post .then method never gets executed neither the .catch method is executed although the server is working fine and returning what I want it to return.

This is my node js controller, doing validation for email exists

```
module.exports.add = function(req, res, next) {
   var user = new User(req.body);
   User.find({email:req.body.email},function(err,doc){
       if(err) {
           {
               err.status = 406;
               return next(err);
           }
       }
           if(doc.length){
               return res.status(409).json({message: 'Email already exist'});
           }
       else {
       user.save(function(err, doc) {
           if (err) {
               err.status = 406;
               return next(err);
           }
           return res.status(201).json({message: 'Your account has been created successfully. Please login to continue.'});
       }) //end of user.save
   } //end of else
  });
};
```

This is my angular controller

```
quizApp.controller("createAcc",['$scope','$http','$location','$timeout','signup',function ($scope,$http,$location,$timeout,signup) {
     $scope.createAcc = function () {
        signup.createAcc($scope.fName, $scope.email, $scope.password)
            .then(function () {
                console.log("it happened");
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                 if(response.status === 409){
                     $scope.emailExist = true;
                }
                console.log("12345");

            });
    }
}


]);
```

This is my angular service

```
quizApp.factory('signup', ['$http',function ($http) {
    return {
        createAcc : function (fName,email,password) {
            var data = {fName:fName,email:email,password:password};
            return $http.post('/api/v1/user/add',data)
        }
        }
}]);
```

So now the problem is, my server is doing the right validation and sending me the status of 409 i.e, email exists but in my angularjs controller the .then function or the .catch function never runs. In the console it just throws an error of 409 but the .then function or the .catch function never gets executed. I have also tried with .success( function successCallback()}, function errorCallback(){} ) , that doesn't work either. I don't understand where I am doing wrong, everything works fine with Postman (the application) though but I am unable to debug the issue here. I think I am doing something wrong in my angular code , can anyone please tell me why my .then and .catch function never gets executed?

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: no it just shows a status error of 409 which i am sending from the server

Comment: where did you call that createAcc?

Comment: i called it in an a tag , which its clicked it will fire up the function createAcc.

Comment: looks like this : <a ng-click="createAcc()" class="btn btn-primary">sign up</a>

Comment: `response.status === 409` should be `err.status === 409`. Doesn't fix the main problem though. I assume you don't remove console.logs with a build system.

Answer (score 0):

inject the `$q` to the factory also

change

```
['$http','$q',function ($http) {
```

to

```
['$http','$q',function ($http,$q) {
```

Comment: okay , but how that's gonna help ? I am sorry i am not so good with $q method

Comment: Injecting something and then not using it is unlikely to help. It's sloppy style, but not the cause of the issue. In this case, the `$q` is injected, but simply being ignored by the function. Better to remove `'$q'` from the array altogether.

Comment: do some reading on dependency injection and you will understand why it is necessary to have the same dependencies injected in the exact same order in both the array and as a parameter -- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: okay i got it, i was actually testing with $q.defer but didnt work as well .